# Clipboard management plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap giving an error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, clipboard, phonegap

I am working on the PhoneGap application. I need to use the copy to clipboard functionality for the app. For this, I have tried many Plugins but got the same errors.

Right now I am using the plugin

> eeschiavo/cordova-plugin-clipboard forked from
>   danielsogl/cordova-plugin-clipboard

Git Url: https://github.com/eeschiavo/cordova-plugin-clipboard

The plugin installed without any errors.

As per the doc, I am using the same example

```
var text = "Hello World!";

cordova.plugins.clipboard.copy(text);

cordova.plugins.clipboard.paste(function (text) { alert(text); });
```

But when I created the build and run on my device It's giving me the error when I checked by debugging on safari.

> undefined is not an object

**What I tried**

- re-installed the plugin
- updated the PhoneGap version which is 9.0.0 now.
- removed platform IOS and added again.

but nothing worked.